# Python vlc allow remote-control

Tags: python, vlc

I am working on some python code that would play a MP3 and allows for remote control.  This code would run on a Raspberry PI("Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)").

This is something supported by vlc.  Here is a vlc equivalent(this worked on version 3.0.20) run from terminal on a MAC:

```
/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC --server-port 8080 --play-and-exit --http-user=abc --http-password=abc --play-and-exit 
  /Users/joe/Music/test.mp3 \
```

Following is the python code:

```
import time
import vlc

vlc_options = "--server-port 8080"
# vlc_options = "--http-host 127.0.0.1:90"
# vlc_options = "--sout=#transcode{acodec=flac}:std{access=http,mux=flac,dst=192.168.1.253:8080}"

instance = vlc.Instance(vlc_options)
media_player = instance.media_player_new()
media = vlc.Media("/Users/joe/Music/test.mp3")
media_player.set_media(media)

media_player.audio_set_volume(30)

# start playing video
media_player.play()


time.sleep(300)
```

It's throwing an error:

```
Warning: option --server-port no longer exists.
```

Now I understand I need the LUA http interface library, but I am not seeing any packages, extensions for vlc or cvlc.

Appreciate some feedback.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Replace

```
vlc_options = "--server-port 8080"
```

with

```
vlc_options = "--extraintf=http --http-port=8080"
```

This option enables the HTTP interface for remote control.

Comment: This worked in playing the MP3 and showing the remote control. There is still an issue with the Remote Control Interface - it shows an empty playlist, where I cannot pause/play the currently playing MP3 or adjust the volume.

Comment: Using subprocess worked:

def vlc_subproc(mp3):

  vlc_command = [
    "/usr/bin/cvlc",
    "--extraintf", "http",
    "--http-host", "192.168.1.253",
    "--http-port", "8080",  # You can change this port if needed
    "--http-password", "vlc",
    "--play-and-exit",
    mp3
  ]

  # Launch VLC with the web interface
  vlc_process = subprocess.Popen(vlc_command)
  # vlc_process = subprocess.run(["vlc_command"], shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)

  # Print the URL to access the web interface
  print("VLC Web Interface URL: http://localhost:8080")